# Cordova/JavaScript add image to resources

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, imageurl

I am fairly new at Cordova and JavaScript.

I have JSON file that stores URL of images.

What I am trying to do is to read an image from the device and store it into resources and save the URL to the JSON config to be able to show it later.

How can it be done?

And if not, what is the best approach to upload images from the device and show them in my app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question for reference

It doesn't seem that it is possible. I used localStorage instead of JSON config file to store the configuration. And i store the images data in localStorage.